# tengo un problema al compilar mi Código utilizando pyinstaller

Tags: python

Estoy intentado compilar mi Código utilizando la siguientes línea de comando `pyinstaller  --windowed --onefile name-scrip.py` cuando compilo mi código sin el `--windowed` se ejecuta el .exe de lo mas bien pero le agrego el `--windowed` me arroja el siguiente error

> "Failed to execute scrip"

El Código que quiero compilar es el siguiente

````
from tkinter import *
from speedtest import Speedtest

def update_text():
    speed_test = Speedtest()
    download = speed_test.download()
    upload = speed_test.upload()
    download_speed = round(download / (10**6), 2)
    upload_speed = round(upload / (10**6), 2)
    down_label.config(text= "Download Speed - " + str(download_speed) + "Mbps") 
    up_label.config(text= "Upload Speed - " + str(upload_speed) + "Mbps") 


root = Tk()
root.title("Internet Speed Tracker")
root.geometry('300x300')
button = Button(root, text="Get Speed", width=30, command=update_text)
button.pack()
down_label = Label(root, text="")
down_label.pack()
up_label = Label(root, text="")
up_label.pack()

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Como recomendación, añade el mensaje completo de error.

Comment: te recomiendo usar esta [auto-py-to-exe](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe) con el cual podras crear ejecutables de manera sencilla saludos!